# Getting null attribute in org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge initialization

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using spark with scala, and what I am doing is  parsing a JSON file containing wikidata items, combining it with some extra information and creating a new JSON file. In doing so, I am creating a set of `WikidataItem` items where each item contains a set of  edges to other `Wikidata` items. The edges are instance of `org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge`. This class contains tree (`var`) attributes `srdId, dstId, attr`.

My problem is the following: whenever the I  call the constructor of `Edge` by  using  `new Edge(srcID=1,dstId=2,attr=3)`, the `attr` field is actually null. Instead a new field of the form `attr$mcl$sp`is created which holds the value of attr. The value is accessible in general by calling `Edge.attr` but when I am serializing my `WikidataItems`, the edges contain in the JSON file 4 fields, namely `srcId, dstId, attr, attr$mcl$sp`, where `attr=null`. Any idea why is this happening and how is it faced?

In studying this phenomenon, I created a simple test where I just create a new `Edge` and then I run it through a debugger. The problem persists in this simple case as well.

The code that generates the problem is displayed below. Although I stress that the problem lies in the fact that internally when an `Edge` is created the value of the attribute `attr` remains null. This can be easily seen running just the `foo` method below and using a debugger.

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge
import java.io.StringWriter
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule


def toJson(obj: Any): String = {
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val out = new StringWriter
mapper.writeValue(out, obj)
return out.toString()
}

def foo()={
 val edge=new Edge(1,2,3)
 println(toJson(edge))
}
```

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: so if you add: println(edge.attr) it will print null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it happens only with Scala's primitive numeric types. As a workaround, you can try with java's Integer, which works quite well with Scala:

```
scala> val edge = Edge[java.lang.Integer](1, 2, 3)
scala> println(toJson(edge))
{"srcId":1,"dstId":2,"attr":3}
```